# "=" in python different from C?

Tags: python

I am confused by the meaning of "=" in python, like codes below:

```
q=[1,2,3,4]
p=q
x=p.pop()
print p,q
p.append(x)
print p,q
p.insert(1,0)
print p,q
p.remove(4)
print p,q
```

It seems that each time I changes p, then q also changes as well! How can that happen?

Comment: [Facts and myths about Python names and values](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Comment: How on earth did you infer that this is this any different from C? In C, you would be passing around a pointer to the array. Changing the contents of `*p` would change the contents`*q`, because they reference the same block of memory.

Comment: Thanks for clarification